# problem installing tor on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, tor

I'm trying to install Tor on ubuntu 12.10, I followed the instruction on [upubuntu](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/08/install-tor-browser-bundle-from-ppa-on.html),  but when I paste `sudo apt-get install tor-browser` (the third line) in my terminal, this is what I see:

```
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto tor-browser
```

that means that it read the packages (first line), it developed the tree of dependences (second line), it read the information on the status but it can't find the package of tor browser. Any suggestion?
thanks in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should download the tor package from [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en)

And then, uncompress the package and then, if you want a direct acces you can create a .desktop file with the following contents
`#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open`
`Version=1.0`
`Type=Application` 
`Terminal=false`
`Exec=/path/to/tor`
`Name=Tor` Or whatever you want to name it
`Comment=Anonymous Browsing` This is for easier location in the dash
`Icon=/path/to/icon`

Answer (score 0):

Do [this](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian-vidalia.html.en) those are official Tor repositories:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this there dont forget to change the distribution:

```
deb     http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION> main
```

Then type those commands:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
sudo gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now update:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vidalia deb.torproject.org-keyring
```

And finally install tor:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

What Ubuntubro wrote is bulding tar package and it's not best you can do first find repositories and thats the last thing you do install .tar